# how to make a pre-trained vectors for other language (word2vec)?

Tags: c, python-2.7, gensim, word2vec

I want to try to implement word2vec to Vietnamase language, but I'm confused about the pre-trained vectors, when I tried to use in the English language I use Google News-vectors-negative300.bin.gz (about 3.4GB) for pre-trained vectors and it works good. if i do with vietnam language should I make the data pre-trained vectors themselves ??
how to make a pre-trained vectors such as Google News-vectors-negative300.bin.gz, then I try to convert Google News-vectors-negative300.bin to text format the result as:

3000000 300

0.001129 -0.000896 0.000319 0.001534 0.001106 -0.001404 -0.000031 -0.000420 -0.000576 0.001076 -0.001022 -0.000618 -0.000755 0.001404 -0.001640 -0.000633 0.001633 -0.001007 -0.001266 0.000652 -0.000416 -0.001076 0.001526 -0.000275 0.000140 0.001572 0.001358 -0.000832 -0.001404 0.001579 0.000254 -0.000732 -0.000105 -0.001167 0.001579

how to change a letter or word into the form above ??

Answer (score 0):

you should train model with your language data. it is possible with using "decode" and "encode" function in python. before the train model with your sentences you should unicode your sentences words.

```
for sentence in sentences:
    for word in sentence:
        word = word.decode('utf-8')
```

after this your model can be train with any language supported by "utf-8" :)